# Monitoring EBS volumes for istances with CloudWatch Agent and CDK

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to set up a way to monitor disk usage for instances belonging to an AutoScaling Group, and add an alarm when the volumes associated to the instances are almost full.

Since it seems there are no metrics normally offered by Amazon to do that, I resorted using the CloudWatch Agent to get what I wanted. So far so good, I can create graphs and alarms for the metrics I want using the CloudWatch console.

My issue is how to automate everything with CDK. How can I automate the creation of the metric for each instance, without knowing the instance id beforehand? Is there a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can install and config CloudWatch agent via EC2 user data and the auto scaling group uses launch template to launch EC2 instance. All of those things can be done by AWS CDK.

There is an example from [this open source project](https://github.com/tuna/opentuna/blob/master/lib/tuna-manager.ts#L75-L102) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you could take is using [AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-state-about.html). Essentially, you install an SSM agent for your instances, and create an SSM Document (think Shell/Python script) that will run your setup script/automation.

You then create a State Manager Association, tying the SSM Document with your instances based on EC2 tags e.g. `Application=MyApp` or `Team=MyTeam`. This way, you don't have to provide any resource ids, just the tag key value pair which could extend multiple instances and future instance replacements. You can schedule it to run at specific times (cron) or at a certain frequency (rate) to enforce state.